# Form moves to weird positions when typing

Tags: html, css, forms

I have this login form for a web application I am building and whenever someone clicks on the input boxes to type the whole screen seems to move around and go out of whack. I'm not sure what's causing this issue but any help is appreciated

I tried using scroll padding but I'm not exactly sure if I used it right or not.

```css
html, body, .grid-container-login {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #B31E1F 50%, #ffffff 50%) no- 
    repeat center center;
    }

    .grid-container-login {
    justify-content: center;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    }

    .welcometothe {
    background-color    : rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
    top                 : 0px;
    height              : auto;
    width               : auto;
    position            : absolute;
    margin-left: -4em;
    left                : 60px;
    -ms-transform       : rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform   : rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform           : rotate(0deg);
    font-family         : 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size           : 6vw;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: auto;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: auto;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;
    font-weight: 900;
    color               : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    text-align          : center;
    line-height         : 157.0px;
    align-self: start;

    }

    .raleighpavingapp{

    align-self: start;
    background-color    : rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
    height              : auto;
    width               : auto;
    top: .5em;
    left: 4em;
    position            : relative;
    -ms-transform       : rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform   : rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform           : rotate(0deg);
    font-family         : 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size           : 6vw;
    font-weight         : 900;
    color               : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    text-align          : center;
    line-height         : 157px;
    }

    .form {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 7vw;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 
    0, 0.24);
    }
    .login-form input {
    font-family:'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 18px;
    }
    .login-form button {
    font-family: 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    background: #b31e1f;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .grid-container-login img{
    margin-top: 5vw;
    max-width: 40%;

    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .welcometothe {
        background-color    : rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
        top                 : 0px;
        height              : auto;
        width               : auto;
        position            : absolute;
        margin-left: -2em;
        left                : 60px;
        -ms-transform       : rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform   : rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera 
    */
        transform           : rotate(0deg);
        font-family         : 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-size           : 10vw;
        -moz-text-size-adjust: auto;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: auto;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;
        font-weight: 900;
        color               : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
        text-align          : center;
        line-height         : 157.0px;
        align-self: start;

    }

        .raleighpavingapp{

        align-self: center;
        background-color    : rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
        height              : auto;
        width               : auto;
        top: .5em;
        left: 1em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position            : relative;
        -ms-transform       : rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform   : rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera 
    */
        transform           : rotate(0deg);
        font-family         : 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-size           : 10vw;
        font-weight         : 900;
        color               : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
        text-align          : left;
        line-height         : 100px;
    }
    .grid-container-login img{
        margin-top: 5vw;
        max-width: 80%;

    }

}
```

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form" id="login_form"  name="login_form" method="post" action="">
      <input name="login_user" type="text" id="login_user" 
    placeholder="username" />
      <input name="login_pass" type="password" id="login_pass" placeholder="password" />
      <button> Login </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: based on what you just added, it doesn't jiggle. Which tells me there is something else that is adding elements to these div's ( like a border or padding ) which will skew things if everything is perfectly placed

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the error. Try clearing your browser cache/cookies (and maybe run a malware check?) .. then try again.